# How to slide-transition two components in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, css-transitions

I'm trying to create a Vue.js transition where one component slides in as the other one slides out. I currently have the new component component sliding in the way I want, but I've been unable to get the old component to slide out.

The transition effect I'm going for is similar to the one here at [TakeCareOf](https://takecareof.com/survey/new).

```
    <transition name="slide-fade">
      <reservation-step step="1" :showBack="false">
        <space-selection/>
      </reservation-step>
    </transition>

    <transition name="slide-fade">
      <reservation-step step="2">
        <reservation-type/>
      </reservation-step>
    </transition>

    <transition name="slide-fade">
      <reservation-step step="3">
        <date-selection/>
      </reservation-step>
    </transition>



<style lang='scss'>
.slide-fade-enter-active,
.slide-fade-leave-active {
  transition: all 1s 0.2s;
}
.slide-fade-enter, .slide-fade-leave-active
/* .slide-fade-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */ {
  opacity: 0;
}
.slide-fade-enter {
  transform: translateX(100px);
}
.slide-fade-leave-active {
  transform: translateX(-100px);
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is more of a css animation question than vue.js, but I hope this example is help to you. [On JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sabee/ce7b9njg/12/) . For more information check the official [vue translations documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html)

*template*

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/animate.css@3.5.1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div id="transition-components-demo">

<p>A <input name="component" type="radio" value="v-a" v-model="view"></p>
<p>B <input name="component" type="radio" value="v-b" v-model="view"></p>

<transition 
    name="slide"
>
  <component v-bind:is="view"></component>
</transition>

</div>
```

*vue code*

```
new Vue({
  el: '#transition-components-demo',
  data: {
    view: 'v-a',
  },
  components: {
    'v-a': {
      template: '<div>Компонент А</div>'
    },
    'v-b': {
      template: '<div>Компонент Б</div>'
    }
  }
})
```

*css animation*

```
.slide-leave-active,
.slide-enter-active {
  transition: 1s;
}
.slide-enter {
  transform: translate(100%, 0);
}
.slide-leave-to {
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
}
```

Comment: This is nearly correct. But you missed a point. The old component is still visible, while the new one is already sliding in. Then the new component "jumps upwards" once the old component is fully removed from the DOM.   You need apply some more position: fixed magic as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59344324/page-slide-transition-in-vue

Comment: @Robert his answer is fully correct. Your use case just required that you apply a max-height:0 and opacity:0 and it would work as you wish.